# SQL Ignore duplicate primary keys

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, primary-key

Imagine you have a string of results from a `SELECT` statement:

```
ID (pk)  Name     Address
1        a        b
1        c        d
1        e        f
2        a        b
3        a        d
2        a        d
```

Is it possible to alter the SQL statement to get one record ONLY for the record with ID 1?

I have a `SELECT` statement that displays multiple values which can have the same primary key. I want to only take one of those records, if say, I have 5 records with the same primary key.

SQL: http://pastebin.com/cFCBA2Uy

Screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/D2kEA.png

What I want is to show only one file which is for e.g. File Number: 925, 890

Comment: Which row/version should be displayed by the query, though? And why would you have a PK that allows duplicated to begin with?

Comment: Why do you have duplicate primary keys in the first place?  That defeats their intended purpose...

Comment: Show your table creation script.

Comment: @Siyual . . . You *cannot* have duplicate primary keys.  They are unique and not null by definition.  I imagine that `id` is the primary key on a table used in the query, but a `join` is multiplying the results.

Comment: "Multiple records with the same **primary** key" sounds very much like a "square with sides of different lengths".

Comment: You say you want only one row for id = 1, but how are we supposed to chose?

Comment: @GordonLinoff Touché - @Brian Can you please show your `Select` statement?

Comment: How can primary key have duplicate values? Can you show table structure?

Comment: Hi all. It is not a table structure. It is a select statement and what I want to do is ommit any record which it's primary key is not unique (in the select statement). Updated the question to give u an idea.

Comment: for ID = 1 which of the 3 records do you want to show? and for ID=2 which of the 2 records? Which is the criteria to choose a recond when there are more than one record with the same id?

Comment: It does not matter which one but preferrably I wouldn't have to filter, for say by State = Active

Comment: Use grouping or a where clause to reduce the result set if there's repeating data. Looking at your samples, just add `WHERE [State Description] = 'Active'` to get a single row per ID, assuming there is only one `active` row per ID.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You stated that no matter which row to choose when there are more than one row for the same Id, you just want one row for each id.

The following query does what you asked for:

```
DECLARE @T table
(
    id int, 
    name varchar(50), 
    address varchar(50)
)
INSERT INTO @T VALUES
(1, 'a', 'b'),
(1, 'c', 'd'),
(1, 'e', 'f'),
(2, 'a', 'b'),
(3, 'a', 'd'),
(2, 'a', 'd');

WITH A AS
(
    SELECT 
        t.id, t.name, t.address,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS RowNumber
    FROM
        @T t
)
SELECT
    A.id, A.name, A.address
FROM
    A
WHERE
    A.RowNumber = 1
```

But I think there should be a criteria. If you find one, express your criteria as the ORDER BY inside the OVER clause.

EDIT:

Here you have the result:

```
+----+------+---------+
| id | name | address |
+----+------+---------+
|  1 | a    | b       |
|  2 | a    | b       |
|  3 | a    | d       |
+----+------+---------+
```

Disclaimer: the query I wrote is non-deterministic, different conditions (indexes, statistics, etc) might lead to different results.